# Adding custom fonts with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, quill, react-quill

I'm not able to make custom functionality work for react-quill with nextjs.

I've tried the proposed solutions from other threads([for example this](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/273))
but adding custom properties does not seem to be handled.

Code example:

loading react-quill dynamically

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(
  import('react-quill').then((mod) => {
    const Quill = mod.default.Quill;
    var Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
    Quill.register(Font, true);
    return mod;
  }),
  { ssr: false } 
);
```

Modules

```
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    
    [
      {
        font: [
          'monospace',
          'serif',
          'raleway',
          'montserrat',
          'lato',
          'rubik',
          'roboto'        
          ],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Usage:

```
 <ReactQuill
      theme="snow"
      value={value}
      modules={modules}
      bounds={'.app'}
      formats={formats}
      onChange={(content) => {
        console.log(content);
      }}
/>
```

I've also added the necessary css for fonts and styling:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

/* Set content font-families */
.ql-font-Roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
.ql-font-Raleway {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}
.ql-font-Montserrat {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.ql-font-Lato {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.ql-font-Rubik {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
}
```

Still this shows 'Sens Serif', as I guess this is the fallback font, for all instances. Testing some the CSS hacks in the mentioned thread, I can get them to change to their proper names. However, if I use any other fonts than the three default ones(serif, monspace and sans serif), the `onChange` is not triggered by any change except for the three default ones.

Has anyone got react-quill working properly with NextJS?

I have even tried to apply the whitelist in the dynamic load without any success:

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(
  import('react-quill').then(async (mod) => {
    const { default: RQ } = await import('react-quill');

    var Font = RQ.Quill.import('formats/font');
    Font.whitelist = [
      'monospace',
      'serif',
      'raleway',
      'montserrat',
      'lato',
      'rubik',
      'roboto'
    ];

    const modules = {
      toolbar: [[{ font: Font.whitelist }]],
    };

    RQ.Quill.register(Font, true);
    
    return ({ forwardedRef, ...props }) => (
      <RQ modules={modules} ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />
    );
  }),
  { ssr: false } // This line is important. It's needed to disable server-side render for this component.
);
```